# Linguagem C - Loop infinito, não esta fazendo a comparação de vetores como planejei

Tags: c, c++

Boa tarde.

Estou fazendo um exercício, desenvolvi uma solução porem não esta funcionando, estou há alguns dias tentando resolver porem empaquei.

Escreva um programa que leia a idade e o primeiro nome de 10 pessoas. Seu programa
deve terminar quando uma idade negativa for digitada. Ao terminar, seu programa deve
escrever o nome e a idade das pessoas mais jovens e mais velhas.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int idade[10];
    int troca_idade;
    char nome[10][20];
    char troca_nome[20];

    for (i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("Digite o %i nome: ",i);
        fgets(nome[i],20,stdin);
        setbuf(stdin,NULL);
        printf("Digite a idade: ");
        scanf("%i",&idade[i]);
        setbuf(stdin,NULL);
        if (idade[i]<0){
            break;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        if (idade[i]<idade[i+1]){ // Se a posição atual for menor que a seguinte não faz nada, se for diferente começa.Lembrando que estou espelhando a posição da idade com os nomes.

        }
        else{
            troca_idade=idade[i];//troca_idade esta com maior valor
            // troca_nome=nome[0];
            strcpy(troca_nome, nome[i]);

            idade[i]=idade[i+1];//idade[i] esta com o valor menor
            //nome[i]=troca_nome[0];
            strcpy(nome[i],nome[i+1]);


            idade[i+1]=troca_idade; //A posição a frente (i+1) esta com o maior vetor
            //nome[i+1]=troca_nome[0];
            strcpy(nome[i+1],troca_nome);

            printf("\n%i",i);
            i=0; //Se for feita uma alteração zera o contador, para refericação de todo o vetor novamente, só sai do loop quando na mudar nada de lugar.
        }
    }

    for (i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("idade: %i nome: %s ",idade[i],nome[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A logica e a seguinte, se a posição posterior for maior que a atual ambas trocam de valor, a cada vez que troca zera o contador, para reverificar tudo, só sai do Loop quando não fizer mais nenhuma modificação !

Acredito que o problema esteja no contador i do FOR, quando mando imprimir so aparece o valor 2.

Sei que é um problema simples e banal, mas fiquei alguns dias tentando resolver. E as soluções que tento esta dando perigo no compilador, nem chego a testa-las.

Comment: Note que o índice de seu array varia de 0 a 9. Você faz o loop ` for(i=0;i<10;i++){` mas logo a seguir o if `if (idade[i]<idade[i+1]){`, ou seja para i = 9 tentará acessar idade[10] que está fora do limite de seu array.

Answer (score -1):

Muito obrigado !
Consegui deixar o código um pouco mais certo! A partir do momento que liberou o Loop vi alguns erros a mais e corrigi. Está praticamente funcionando. 
Só estou com um pequeno problema as vezes quando tem que realizar muitas mudanças a primeira posição fica com valor errada, só troca de posição umas 2x.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int idade[10];
    int troca_idade;
    char nome[10][20];
    char troca_nome[20];

    for (i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("Digite o %i nome:",i);
        scanf("%s",&nome[i]);
        setbuf(stdin,NULL);
        printf("Digite a idade:");
        scanf("%i",&idade[i]);
        setbuf(stdin,NULL);
        if (idade[i]<0){
            break;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<9;i++){
        if (idade[i]<idade[i+1]){ // Se a posição atual for menor que a seguinte não faz nada, se for diferente começa.Lembrando que estou espelhando a posição da idade com os nomes.

        }
        if(idade[i]>idade[i+1])
            {
            troca_idade=idade[i];//troca_idade esta com maior valor
            strcpy(troca_nome, nome[i]);

            idade[i]=idade[i+1];//idade[i] esta com o valor menor
            strcpy(nome[i],nome[i+1]);


            idade[i+1]=troca_idade; //A posição a frente (i+1) esta com o maior vetor
            strcpy(nome[i+1],troca_nome);


            i=0; //Se for feita uma alteração zera o contador, para refericação de todo o vetor novamente, só sai do loop quando na mudar nada de lugar.
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("idade:%i nome:%s\n",idade[i],nome[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Eu consigo corrigir mas com gambiarra com outro loop ou aumentando o vetor, mas quero entender oque acontece. Para da próxima vez saber como reagir !

Sugestão de valores pra teste **nessa ordem**: 987,98,688,65,65,699,44,323,33,8.